# Functional Programming à la 1940s: Minimalistic Implementation of Factorial

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, factorial

I have watched the amazing talk by John Hughes titled [Why Functional Programming Matters](https://youtu.be/XrNdvWqxBvA) a couple of times and only recently decided to actually try implementing the "minimalist" version of booleans, integers, and of course factorial, as shown in the [video](https://youtu.be/XrNdvWqxBvA?t=1m28s).

I implemented `true`, `false`, `ifte`, `zero`, `one`, `two`, `iszero`, `decr` and finally `fact` [here](https://repl.it/Nm3P/7) as follow:

```
-- boolean
true x y = x
false x y = y
ifte bool t e = bool t e

-- positive integers
three f x = f $ f $ f x
two f x = f $ f x
one f x = f x
zero f x = x 

-- add and multiplication
add m n f x = m f $ n f x
mul m n f x = m (n f) x 

-- is zero check
iszero n =  n (\_ -> false) true

-- decrement
decr n = 
  n (\m f x -> f (m f zero))
    zero
    (\x->x)
    zero


-- factorial
fact n =
  ifte (iszero n)
    one
    (mul n (fact (decr n)))
```

### Problem

I tested every function, and they all compile and work perfectly, except for `decr` and `fact`.

Even though John Hughes promises at [6:37](https://youtu.be/XrNdvWqxBvA?t=6m37s) that his implementation of `decr` works, it fails to compile with the following error:

> error: Variable not in scope: incr

I am not certain how `incr` should be implemented in `(\m f x -> f (m incr zero))`.

Now if I define them as `incr = (+1)` and change the definition of `decr` to the following, then `decr` compiles and works fine, but `fact` still causes compilation failure.

```
decr n = 
  n (\m f x -> f (m incr x))
    zero
    (\x->x)
    zero'
```

Is there a bug in the lambda `(\m f x -> f (m incr zero))` used in the definition of `decr`, or should `incr` be defined differently?

### Update

When I define `incr` as `incr n = (\f x -> f (n f x))`, `decr n` works fine, but `fact n` fails to compile. Here's the readable portion of the error message:

> factorial.hs:30:1: error:
>       • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
>
> ...
>
> | fact n =
>      | ^^^^^^^^...
>
> ...
>
> factorial.hs:33:6: error:
>       • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> • In the third argument of ‘ifte’, namely ‘(mul n (fact (decr n)))’
>   In the expression: ifte (iszero n) one (mul n (fact (decr n)))
>   In an equation for ‘fact’:
>       fact n = ifte (iszero n) one (mul n (fact (decr n)))
> ```
>
> ...
>
> |     (mul n (fact (decr n)))
>      |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Note: the complete error message is several pages long.

Comment: "*Variable not in scope: incr*" is because you did not yet implement `incr`, but it's really simple: increment one of those numbers! Not the integer `+1` increment, but for that church encoding.

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the problem *in the question itself* (N.B. not at an off-site resource).

Comment: @Bergi That's where I am stuck; even though I also believe that `incr` should be very simple to implement, but I can't quite perceive the meaning of incrementing a "church encoding" (I assume that by "church encoding" you mean the positive integers that I have in the code snippet).

Comment: @DanielWagner I copied the code inside the question, as requested. Thank you

Comment: @AriaPahlavan, I should mention that your program relies upon Haskell's built-in recursion mechanism (when `fact` calls `fact`) – the answer I provided uses lambdas to achieve recursion

Comment: @AriaPahlavan How could a function `incr` look, so that `incr one` or `incr (\f x -> f x)` becomes `\f x -> f (f x)`?

Comment: @Bergi `incr = (\n f x -> f (n f x))` is how I think it should be implemented, and `decr n` works fine, But `fact n` doesn't compile.

Comment: @AriaPahlavan Yes, that looks good (although I'd have written `incr n = \f x -> f (n f x)`).

Comment: Whoa, this looks like an interesting case. Not sure if its a bug in the compiler…

Comment: @Bergi Oh yeah I originally wrote it like `incr n = \f x -> f (n f x))` but then changed it because for some reason I thought that would fix the issue where the compilation would never finish (but obviously I was wrong). Anyways so you also believe that this should work and the reason it doesn't finish compiling could be a bug in the compiler. I guess I could register a GHC bug report.

Comment: @AriaPahlavan At first you might want to check whether it's a GHC issue, or just something that repl.it does. It's a useful tool for fiddling around, but compiler bug reports should be done with a local instance of the compiler that you have complete control over (using latest version and trying out some command-line flags).

Comment: @Bergi I compiled it using the latest version of GHC (installed on my system), and I got compilation failure. I updated the question with some portion of the error message. (the error message was very long)

Comment: @Bergi, it's definitely not a bug in the compiler. The problem is that `fact` has a rank-2 type, so it requires a type signature: `fact :: (forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (t -> t) -> t -> t`. Separately, the definition of `decr` is quite wrong; it has a surprising type and calculates incorrect results.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, that's what I figured as well after trying it (and assigning some types with the help of LiberalTypeSynonyms and RankNTypes). It's only the "hanging instead of reporting an error" behaviour encountered in repl.it that I would consider a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're really close

I can show you how to do this using [Church's encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) in JavaScript, but not in Haskell, because I don't know how to make some simple combinators type-check in Haskell (`U` below)

Because JavaScript is strictly evaluated, predicate branches must be wrapped in a lambda

Go ahead and run the snippet – we calculate `8!`

```js
const True = a => b =>
  a ()
  
const False = a => b =>
  b ()
  
const IsZero = n =>
  n (x => False) (True)

const Succ = n =>
  f => x => f (n (f) (x))
  
const Pred = n =>
  f => x => n (g => h => h (g (f))) (u => x) (u => u)

const Mult = m => n =>
  f => m (n (f))
  
const Add = m => n =>
  m (Succ) (n)

const one = f => x =>
  f (x)
  
const two =
  Add (one) (one)
  
const four =
  Add (two) (two)
  
const eight =
  Add (four) (four)

const U = f => f (f)

const Fact = U (f => acc => n =>
  IsZero (n)
    (z => acc) // thunks used for predicate branches
    (z => U (f) (Mult (acc) (n)) (Pred (n)))) (one)
    
const result = 
  Fact (eight)
  
// convert church numeral result to a JavaScript number
console.log ('8! =', result (x => x + 1) (0))
// 8! = 40320
```

If you cheat a little, you can achieve faux laziness by using JavaScript's `?:` ternary operator – I'm only showing this so you can see `Fact` in a more readable form; the above implementation uses *only* lambdas

```js
const IsZero = n =>
  // cheat by returning JavaScript's true/false booleans
  n (x => false) (true)

const Succ = n =>
  f => x => f (n (f) (x))
  
const Pred = n =>
  f => x => n (g => h => h (g (f))) (u => x) (u => u)

const Mult = m => n =>
  f => m (n (f))
  
const Add = m => n =>
  m (Succ) (n)

const one = f => x =>
  f (x)
  
const two =
  Add (one) (one)
  
const four =
  Add (two) (two)
  
const eight =
  Add (four) (four)

const U = f => f (f)

const Fact = U (f => acc => n =>
  IsZero (n)
    ? acc // now we're sorta cheating using JavaScript's ternary here
    : U (f) (Mult (acc) (n)) (Pred (n))) (one)

const result = 
  Fact (eight)
  
console.log ('8! =', result (x => x + 1) (0))
// 8! = 40320
```

Comment: your `pred` is taking `n`, `f`, and `x` as arguments if I am not mistaking, which is different from the implementation I was aiming at (i.e. `decr n = ...`).

Comment: @AriaPahlavan, ah, that is one way to think of it; here's another – *"Pred takes a Church numeral `n` and returns a new Church numeral"*

Comment: It's no different than (eg) your `mul m n f x = m (n f) x` – `mul` doesn't take *four* arguments *m*, *n*, *f*, and *x*; that wouldn't make any sense –
Multiplication takes *two* arguments (Church numerals *m* and *n* in this case) and it returns a Church numeral (`\f x -> m (n f) x`)

Comment: The JavaScript version you provided is I believe the correct way of implementing this as is defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding. But does that mean the `decr n` is implemented incorrectly?

Comment: Church's encoding of [*pred*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Derivation_of_predecessor_function) in Haskell would be `pred n = \f x -> n (\g h -> g (g f)) (\u -> x) (\u -> u)` – not sure why Hughes deviates from this encoding

Comment: I think the increment lambda should be `inc = (\g h -> h (g f))`.

Comment: But that's is an invalid η-reduction; `\g h -> h (g f)` is not equivalent to (Church's) `\g h x -> h (g h x)`; the `x` is on the *inside* of the `()` – if you're trying to be clever tho, you can use Haskell's `(.)`: `\g h -> h . (g f)`; but of course that's cheating

Answer (score 1):

First, let's try to explicitly type everything. Naïvely, all this stuff is parameterised on some type that the Church functions deal with:

```
type Logical a = a -> a -> a
type Nat a = (a->a) -> a->a

-- boolean
true, false :: Logical a
true x y = x
false x y = y

ifte :: Logical a -> a -> a -> a
ifte = id

incr :: Nat a -> Nat a
incr n f = f . n f

-- integer “literals”
zero, one, two, three :: Nat a
three = incr two
two   = incr one
one   = incr zero
zero _ = id

-- addition and multiplication
add, mul :: Nat a -> Nat a -> Nat a
add m n f = m f . n f
mul m n f = m $ n f

-- zero check
isZero :: Nat a -> Logical a
isZero n = n (const false) true
```

...ok, here we run into the first problem:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Logical a’ with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      isZero :: forall a. Nat a -> Logical a
    at /tmp/wtmpf-file7834.hs:25:1-28
• In the expression: n (const false) true
```

The issue is that we try to use the `Nat`-church-numbers as a function not on the underlying `a` type that the result `Logical` is supposed to work with, but on those logicals themselves. I.e. it's actually

```
isZero :: Nat (Logical a) -> Logical a
```

It gets worse for `decr` – this doesn't work:

```
decr :: Nat a -> Nat a
decr n = n (\m f x -> f (m incr x))
           zero
           id
           zero
```

because you're trying to use the number for both a logical purpose as in `isZero`, which requires injecting another `Nat` layer, but also for just passing on/incrementing. In traditional Hindley-Milner, you'd need to decide on one of these, so it's not possible to make it typecheck.

In modern Haskell, you *can* make it typecheck, by *making the argument polymorphic*:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, UnicodeSyntax #-}
decr :: (∀ α . Nat α) -> Nat a
```

To avoid carrying around the quantifier, we might make another synonym:

```
type ANat = ∀ α . Nat α
```

then it's just

```
decr :: ANat -> Nat a
```

And that technique works for the factorial as well:

```
fact :: ANat -> Nat a
fact n = ifte (isZero n)
      one
      (mul n $ fact (decr n))
```